# Webpack and npm node

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

We can run javascript code directly into our browser.So,why we should use webpack and install node using npm for javascript and how to use webpack into our project files?

Comment: I think your misunderstanding what Webpack is, and what it's used for. It is a module blunder, so is used to actually build your project, that will then run in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Javascript in your browser because each browser has a [javascript engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines) running, making it able to interpret and execute the script. Google chrome has the V8 engine, while firefox uses the SpiderMonkey engine.

What `node` does is to take one of those engines (V8, from chrome) and use it to run javascript through the command line, making it possible to create a backend server built with javascript!

[Webpack](https://medium.com/the-self-taught-programmer/what-is-webpack-and-why-should-i-care-part-1-introduction-ca4da7d0d8dc), on the other hand, is something completely unrelated and is used to build your applications (for instance, to bundle all your js files into a single js file and other useful features that you may want when you're building a complex JS application).

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is a bundler. It helps manage, maintain and package up project dependencies.

If you want to create a simple website (a few or no dependencies), webpack might feel as an overkill and frankly it is. But if you want to create something modern and robust, a bundler is practically a must.

Webpack provides a lot of features that you might not even know about that you actually need if you just starting out with webdev. You can read about them on the project site.